# How to pattern-match multiple targets with their prerequisities?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm starting out with makefile and I am a bit puzzled about how patterns work. I have multiple different targets, each with a name-matching prerequisite. I would like to have a variable storing all the "stems" of the targets and prerequisities at the top, and then just adding the prefix/suffix and a common recipe for all of them. So far I have tried:

```
names = stem1 stem2 stem3

all: $(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt) $(names:%=dir/another_%.txt)

$(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt): $(names:%=sourcedir/yetanother_%.xlsx)
    echo $@
    echo prerequisite_with_the_same_stem_as_current_target
```

Even though this makes all the targets one by one, the prerequisities for each target are listed all, not just the one that matches with the current `%(names)` of the target. The reason I need it to match is because I then supply the current target and its single prerequisite to a script, which then makes the target. How to pattern-match each prerequisite with its one target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misconception that you have is about how `make` handles lists. If you have a variable:

```
names = stem1 stem2 stem3
```

then `make` handles this as a list *but instantiates the whole list contents all at once* every time you name this variable. *It does not* do a one-per-one operation on list contents, because that would be close to uncontrollable, depending on the situation. Instead it resorts to simple text replacement, thus your line

```
all: $(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt) $(names:%=dir/another_%.txt)
```

is parsed&variable-replaced very simple into a string:

```
all: dir/prefix_stem1.txt dir/prefix_stem2.txt dir/prefix_stem3.txt ...etc...
```

The iterative list handling happens only within `$(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt)` and so on, while the line itself, after variable-replacement, just is text which is fed to the second parsing step.

Along the same line your rule:

```
$(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt): $(names:%=sourcedir/yetanother_%.xlsx)
```

expands to

```
dir/prefix_stem1.txt dir/prefix_stem2.txt dir/prefix_stem3.txt: sourcedir/yetanother_stem1.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem2.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem3.xlsx
```

which is a short-hand notation for the three rules:

```
dir/prefix_stem1.txt: sourcedir/yetanother_stem1.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem2.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem3.xlsx
dir/prefix_stem2.txt: sourcedir/yetanother_stem1.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem2.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem3.xlsx
dir/prefix_stem3.txt: sourcedir/yetanother_stem1.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem2.xlsx sourcedir/yetanother_stem3.xlsx
```

and nothing else. Obviously you told make that each target depends *on all* of the prerequisites.

With a little tweaking and [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) you can achiev your goal, though:

```
MY_TARGETS :=  $(names:%=dir/prefix_%.txt) # create full target names

$(MY_TARGETS) : dir/prefix_%.txt : sourcedir/yetanother_%.xslx
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Is it common formatting in make to have upper-case variables?

Comment: Umm..I don't know. I picked this style up from the manual. Then again, in my library [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) I do the reverse, mainly to set library names apart from user names hopefully.